# Left side of absolute div disappears when page is scaled down

Tags: html, css

On http://www.posterlion.com/ the left side disappears when you make the window smaller by the browser. The horizontal scrollbar appears though but I can't get to it anymore by scrolling to the left. The content is centered through a absolute div. How do i prevent this from happening?

```
position:relative;left:50%;margin-left:-517px; 
width:1015px; overflow:visible; background-color: #FFFFFF; padding: 10px;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice to centered tour layout is using `margin: 0px auto` instead of absolute positioning.

In your case you should remove your absolute positioning, create some div which contain all your layout (`<div id='wrapper'></div>` can be standard in this case) and set its `margin` to `auto`.

By:

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: yourWidth;
}
```

Comment: thanks, that helped. Thankfully the #lwe was already a wrapper which made things easy

Answer (score 0):

In your given **CSS** add

```
min-width: 1050px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is Css to update :-

```
#lwe {
       width: 1015px;
      overflow: visible;
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
     padding: 10px;
     margin: 0 auto;
```

}